# Magento 2.3.5 Installation Issue, Can any one help?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am trying to install Magento 2.3.5 and facing issue in my local environment.

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I had the same issue. Found a workaround on GitHub. Installed 100%. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/28055

Comment: @blackcat_au Thank you so much, it's work